# Manual Bibliography Entries in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I need to create a bibliography that meets very specific style guidelines not compatible with any packages in LaTeX. Therefore, I need to be able to enter the exact text I want to appear in my bibliography. However, I also want to reuse bibliography entries as I would with BibTeX, keeping a central bibliography in a separate file from my documents.

How can I keep my exact bibliography entries in a database similar to BibTeX so that I will be able to \cite them in my documents? (I do not insist on the command being `\cite`, but I want it to have the same effect as `\cite` would in a traditional bibliography.)

Comment: The package `biblatex` offers the best 'high-level' programmability for bibliography/citation styles for LaTeX; it will use a standard `.bib` file.  Other than that, your question is actually really vague.  Can you give some idea as to what the output looks like?  If there are very strict and complete rules, does that mean there is actually a style guide you can link to?

Comment: If your main tex file is named `main.tex`, you could edit the file `main.bbl` by hand to add the specific entries to the given specifications. However, have you considered using the `makebst` utility (part of the `custom-bib` package) to create a highly customized style file? You may just be able to emulate the special style guidelines.

Comment: Jon, the specific style guideline can be found in _Evidence Explained_ by Elizabeth Shown Mills. I need to type the exact bibliography entry as it will appear in the bibliography, but I want to keep it in a database like BibTeX does so that I have a master bibliography and I can cite items in it from multiple documents and have LaTeX ensure that the typeset bibliography contains all (and only) those references that I have actually cited in that particular document.

Comment: You could put the formatted entry in e.g. the note field and write a bib-style which uses only this field. But it would naturally much saner (but also much more work) to extend the datamodel of biblatex and to adapt or write a suitable style.